# Entity Framework - List of Class having Same class to parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, entity

I have a Parent class of Users and it has Followers list like the following.
The User class has a list of follower class..

```
public class User
{ 
    public User()
    { 
        Followers = new HashSet<Follower>(); 
    }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string username { get; set; }
      
    public virtual ICollection<Follower> Followers { get; set; }
}
```

and the Follower class has other user who follows the parent user.
like this

```
public class Follower
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}
```

But when i add object to the list inside the User table,

```
parentUser.Followers.Add(new Follower { user = childUser});
//The parentClass is object of User class
```

everything looks fine but when the compiler goes through the `_myDb.SaveChanges();` the Follower User is changed to the parent users.

and I checked database, it has the following value.

```
+----+--------+
| ID | UserID |
+====+========+
| 1  | 1      |
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need 2 relation between user and Follower

one for specifying parent user of each follower and one for exact user of each follower(childUser) am I correct?

**Edit:**

base on your answer I spouse this helps you:
I spouse this is your answer :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Follow> Followers { get; set; }//followers of this user
    public ICollection<Follow> Followings { get; set; }//users that followed by this user
}
public class Follow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FollowerUserId { get; set; }//who
    public User FollowerUser { get; set; }
    public int FollowingUserId { get; set; }//followed who
    public User FollowingUser { get; set; }
}
```

and in OnModelCreating :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Followers).WithOne(y => y.FollowingUser).HasForeignKey(y => y.FollowingUserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Followings).WithOne(y => y.FollowerUser).HasForeignKey(y => y.FollowerUserId);
```

Comment: Its like the parent User has a collection of Follower users. i have already tried the collection of `List<Users> followers;` inside the User class but it still gives me some kind of error.